# Centre of charge of the distribution

Tags: dipole-moment

If one has a charge distribution whose monopole moment differs from zero, how can I show that one can always find an origin such that the dipole moment will be zero?

Comment: It sounds like you are SHOUTING here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this proof from Griffiths Electrodynamics 3rd ed. Section 3.4.3:

The dipole moment is defined as:
$\vec{p} = \int \vec{r'} \rho (r') d \tau'$.

You can define a new dipole moment, $\vec{\bar{p}}$, where you have moved the origin to the position given by the vector $\vec{a}$.

$\vec{\bar{p}} = \int (\vec{r'} - \vec{a}) \rho (r') d \tau' = \vec{p} - \vec{a} \int \rho (r') d \tau' = \vec{p} - \vec{a} Q $

Q, the total charge, is the nonzero monopole term, and is independent of coordinate system.

So choose $\vec{a}$ so that $\vec{p} = \vec{a} Q $, and your dipole moment is 0 in the new coordinate system.

Comment: Thank you so much, makes more sense now